# Querying MongoDB using Dates in rmongodb aggregation

Tags: r, mongodb, date-format, aggregation-framework, rmongodb

I am trying to query my MongoDB between two dates/times using `rmongodb`.

My document structure is as following:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5304f93a0d5c9bf99c4e5a57"),
    "field1" : 34
    "field2" : 45
    "field3" : 55
    "time" : ISODate("2015-07-13T22:00:00.000Z")
} 
.
.
.
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5304f93a0d5c9bf99c4e5a57"),
    "field1" : 43
    "field2" : 54
    "field3" : 65
    "time" : ISODate("2015-07-14T22:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Now I want to get all the documents between two dates(original collection has documents from last year). And as I want to aggregate the results of the documents between two days, I am piping this query along with other queries to `mongo.aggregation()` function in `rmongodb`.

```
library(rmongodb)
host <- "myHost"
db <- "myDB"
mongo <- mongo.create(host=host , db=db)
collection <- "myDB_coll"
namespace <- paste(db,collection,sep=".")

time1 <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2015-07-13 00:00:00", tz='GMT'))*86400000
time2 <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2015-07-14 00:00:00", tz='GMT'))*86400000

pipe_1 <- mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$match":{"time":{"$gte":{"$date":"time1"},"$lt":{"$date":"time2"}}}}')
pipe_2 <- mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$group":{"_id":"$myVariable","sum_field1":{"$sum":"$field1"},"sum_field2":{"$sum":"$field2"},"sum_field3":{"$sum":"$field3"}}}')
pipe_3 <- mongo.bson.from.JSON('{"$sort":{"sum_field1":-1}}')

cmd_list <- list(pipe_1,pipe_2,pipe_3)
res <- mongo.aggregation(mongo,namespace,cmd_list)
j <- mongo.bson.value(res,"result")
```

But, the final result `j` is always `integer(0)`. No error is being thrown. I suspect my `pipe_1` query is not returning anything and thus there are no documents for `mongo.aggregation()` to work on. The date/time format I am using is creating problems AFAIK. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**
The following code works perfectly well and gives me all the documents between required dates. But it is not with aggregation. Just one query. AFAIK, I cannot use lists in association with aggregation piping in `rmongodb`. I tried writing the equivalent of below `q` in JSON format. It doesn't work too because we need `match` command for aggregation to work.

```
time1 <- as.POSIXct("2015-07-13 00:00:00",tz='GMT')
time2 <- as.POSIXct("2015-07-14 00:00:00",tz='GMT')
q <- mongo.bson.from.list(list("time" = list("$gte" = time1,"$lt" = time2)))
mongo.find.all(mongo,namespace,q)
```

Comment: So you do realise your query that "works" is passing in dates and the query that "doesn't work" is re-casting dates as numeric types and therefore they do not match. Also what is `$myVariable` here? If it is not actually a field in your document then it's value is effectively `null`, so just use that. Or is it your intention to aggregate by a time period, i.e every 15 minutes? Oh and the Math is wrong anyway, you are multiplying by milliseconds in a day and I think you meant modulo.But really you didn't need to do that. Many things wrong here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thank you for taking time! I figured out that my above query isn't passing dates, that's the reason I posted the question in the first place :) . Anyways, I found a way to send Date formats, but in the old `rmongodb` buffer way and it works great :) . By the way, `$myVariable` is my masked variable for understanding purposes!

Comment: So if you "figured it out" then there is no need for the "question" anymore is there? Either remove it or provide an anwer to how you fixed it, if you feel that other people might "accidently" convert their dates into numerics in the same way you did.

Comment: I will happily delete it! Thank you for your kind suggestion!